# ADF - Get error message from execute pipeline activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement to mail errors in pipeline through logic apps.

I have a master pipeline with an Execute Pipeline activity and a web activity that sends email via logic app.

Problem is I am not sure how to capture the error message from Execute Pipeline activity as the output of this activity is the PipelineRunId for the downstream pipeline mentioned in Execute Pipeline activity...

[image]

Please let me know if there is any method to capture the error here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the below expression:

```
activity('Actname')?.error?.message
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked - please edit out the ')' at the end

Comment: Edited. And glad it helped.

Comment: This is not working when a lookup activity fails inside execute pipeline. I am getting below error:
{"error":{"code":"InvalidRequestContent","message":"The request content is not valid and could not be deserialized: 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: d. Path 'message', line 2, position 192.'."}}

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/56582/logic-app-not-able-to-deserialized-azure-data-fact.html : this query explains the issue in detail